# Referencing a Typescript file causes Intellisense errors in that file

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Typescript 1.3 (and tried with Typescript 1.0.0.0 before upgrading)

I've got an MVC web app project which uses Typescript files. All these .ts files are able to reference each other implicitly without any `///<reference>` statements. I don't have a `_references.ts` file in the project either.

I have now started looking at writing unit tests for this .ts files. I have a separate project in the same solution for tests. I have added jasmine and the jasmine .d.ts file to the project.

When I create a Typescript test class, it is unable to implicitly reference the .ts classes from the web application. I can solve this by introducing a `///<reference>` statement in the test class. However, in doing this, the class from the web app project that I just referenced suddenly gets Intellisense errors all through it, as it is now unable to implicitly reference any of its dependencies.

Do I now need to start explicitly referencing dependencies throughout the Typescript in my web application project? Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: First, I'd try to upgrade your tools to TypeScript 1.3 or 1.4 ... maybe this is an already fixed issue.

Comment: I have had the same problem. I think the easiest way to avoid this issue is to not have the test in a separate project. It seems the implicit referencing is only within projects. I think there was a half-way solution where the test project had the application project as a reference. Then the types was working but intellisens did not..

Comment: @Benjamin - have upgraded to Typescript 1.3 and it makes no difference. Without the <reference> statements, the unit test class can not reference the implementation class. With the <reference> statement, the implementation class can not reference its dependencies.

Comment: @Gustav - my Test project references the main web app project, but unfortunately I can not run the unit test, it complains that the build has failed.

Comment: @SimonGreen Are you using Chutzpah to run the tests?

Comment: @The ZenCoder - no, not yet. Trying with Resharper at the moment. I have moved the test class into the main webapp project now. The good news as that I don't don't have any reference statements and I don't get any compilation errors. The bad news is that at runtime, the references aren't linked in

Comment: I have just put the <reference> statements back into the test class. This works now - it pulls in the reference at runtime, yet now for some reason I don't get the compilation errors on the class being referenced. Moving the class doing the referencing (the test class) into the same project seems to fix that

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use **Chutzpah** instead of Resharper runner.

Chutzpah can be configured using a `chutzpah.json` file in your root test folder directory to automatically include references. Here is an example to include all .ts files from a folder called classes:

```
{
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "References": [
        { "Path": "../classes", "Include": "*.ts", "Exclude": "*Resource*" }
    ]
}
```

With this configuration in place all compiled .ts files from that folder will be included prior to running the tests, which will prevent runtime errors.

https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20references%20setting&referringTitle=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File

Comment: Will the Visual Studio Intellisense pick up on this configuration, and stop it complaining?

Comment: If i don't use any explicit reference statements in typescript, but instead just the chutzpah configuration i don't get any errors whatsoever at build or runtime. The tests run seamlessly even with deep dependencies.

Comment: FYI i use VS 2013 Update 4 with Typescript 1.4 and latest Chutzpah.

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 Update 3 with Typescript 1.3 and have downloaded the  Chutzpah Test Adaptor .vsix file, version 3.3.1, and the Context menu adapter, also 3.3.1. I have removed all the explicit <reference> statements and have created a chutzpah.json file in the root of the project. When I Run the .ts Test using the new context menu item, I get lots of "error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'xyz'" messages

Comment: To clarify, the "Path" attribute is relative to the project's root folder, and I have tried using both "*.ts" and "*.js" in the "Include" attribute

Comment: Yeah. When i reference .js file only i also get TS warnings, but the tests still run correctly. However, when i run with a .ts references configuration only i dont get any errors. Update answer to reflect that.

Comment: OK, I have got it going now, I had to make some changes in the chutzpah.json. I added the Framework attribute. I used the  ** syntax to reference the .ts and .js files - e.g. "Include": ***/Scripts/common/*.ts. Also I had to reference things in the correct order to make sure dependencies were linked in before dependants

Comment: @SimonGreen great :) i am glad you figured it out. Chutzpah is definitely more configurable than Resharper.

Comment: Another question - I want these tests to run as part of our CI setup, which uses TFS to queue builds and run tests. I'm expecting to need to use chutzpah test runner here too - is this possible?

Comment: @SimonGreen Yes it is. I have a powershell script that runs chutzpah test runner in AppVeyor CI.

Comment: @SimonGreen were you able to set everything up? :)

Comment: @ZenCoder - I haven't tried getting the tests to run as part of my TFS CI yet - but thanks for your answer regarding that. As for the initial question, the only way I have been able to avoid the compilation errors, even if using the Chutzpah Test Runner, is to put my test classes in the same project as the application classes.